# Enabling AIF web services

Tags: web-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, aif

I'm trying to set up AIF web services on an instance of an AOS.

Once I'm done with the AIF Web Service component installation, I'm not seeing any .asmx/.svc or otherwise that would provide a WSDL to consume AIF web services.

Is there something I'm missing ?

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\50\AifWebServices\Bin` only holds `Microsoft.Dynamics.IntegrationFramework.WebService.Process.dll` and language named folders holding `Microsoft.Dynamics.IntegrationFramework.WebService.Process.resources.dll`

Also, in `Basic->Setup->Application Integration Framework`, I only have `Endpoints`. I saw some guides mentioning I should have `Service` and `Websites` in there.

I'm patched up to RU8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you actually have to create the document service **AND**, well, the missing menu element is due to a missing AX license we need to purchase so the menu elements appear...